# Firefox insecure channel warning

Tags: ruby, selenium, firefox, https, cucumber

**Background**

I am implementing a OpenId Connect client and as a developer, I am using `http://localhost:8080/myapp/admin` as the callback url.

The flow is:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/admin -> OpenIDProvider -> credentials 
-> http://localhost:8080/myapp/admin?credentials={...}
```

I get this annoying modal saying

> The information you have entered on this page will be sent over an
>   insecure connection and could be read by a third party.

This is not such a big deal when I am testing this manually, but right now I am writing cucumber tests (Ruby) that I want to run, and that execution fails horribly :

> Unexpected modal dialog (text: The information you have entered on
>   this page 
>       will be sent over an insecure connection and could be read by a third party.

**What I've tried so far**

I've tried downgrading firefox to firefox 40.0 as callbacks to http were not a problem before (but I don't remember what version of firefox I had). I've tried setting `devtools.chrome` in firefox to true. I've tried turning off proxy in firefox.

It is worth noting that the cucumber tests don't fail on our app server (since we can obviously use https there):

```
https://myappserver.com/myapp/admin -> OpenIDProvider -> credentials 
-> https://myappserver.com/myapp/admin?credentials={...}
```

Simply changing to `https` isn't an option as the callback url for localhost development is set to `http`

Is there an option in firefox where I can turn these warnings off? Or maybe there is a way to set this option when running cucumber?

Comment: Could you start firefox using selenium and navigate to `about:config`. In this window search for `insecure`. What is the value of the preference `security.warn_submit_insecure`?

Comment: Also googling your error I found this "Firefox gives that error because the page is on HTTPS but your form action is HTTP". Is this the case?

Comment: @RemcoW : I can't find the `security.warn_submit_insecure` and with good reason. It's gone: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/976134

Comment: @RemcoW :  I just know that localhost doesn't use `https` (because we need it to be that way) and I know that the reason this isn't a problem on our app servers is that the appservers use `https`.  What the form uses, I have no idea about..because that's something our OpenID provider has implemented.

Comment: Can you not surround the action you are doing in a try/catch (or the ruby equivalent) and catch the `UnhandledAlertException`? In this you should be able to accept the dialog

Comment: I could. But that isn't the question really. I want to turn these warnings off during cucumber tests as I don't want to litter the cucumber tests with exception handling code.

Comment: Ok, in that case I don't think that's possible.

Comment: What possible benefit is there to using http over https in localhost?

Comment: @maxpleaner : It is mentioned in the question. `Simply changing to https isn't an option as the callback url for localhost development is set to http`

Comment: What I meant is why can't you set the callback url to https?

Comment: Because that is what our provider has set for us. Why are we having this discussion? Changing the callback URL is off-topic and clearly not the question.

Comment: This helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676049/how-to-handle-security-alert-in-firefox-with-selenium